# javascript toggle function to hide and display text - how to add images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently using the below text as a simple way of hiding and displaying my text. What I was trying to do though also was use the css to display the a tag with a background image:

one to have a plus symbol for when the text is hidden.

Then one to have a minus symbol for when the text is displayed and you want to hide the text again.

---

JavaScript:

```
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Show";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Hide";    
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show Further Details & Specification</a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none"><h1>peek-a-boo</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up the CSS for "displayText" to give it a background.

Something like this:

```
#displayText {
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    padding-left:30px;
    background-image:url(../images/plus.png);
}
```

Then swap the image for the alternate state:

```
#displayText.active {
    background-image:url(../images/minus.png);
}
```

So in your code you'll need to add/remove the "active" class name on displayText based on the toggle state.

P.S. It's considered bad form to used "href" for JS events. It's better to use onclick.

```
<a id="displayText" href="javascript://"  onclick="toggle();">
```

Answer (score 2):

Next time try to post your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TW2Le/5/) 
there are some issues with your code, first is better to put event handlers rather than put the javascript code in the href property, is easier to use a variable to save the state of the toggle button. Works almost 99% of the times if you show your elements with inline rather than block

```
var textHidden = true;
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(textHidden) {
    ele.style.display = "inline";
    text.innerHTML = "Show";
    textHidden = false

}
else {
    textHidden = true
    ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "Hide";

}
}​
```

html:

```
<a id="displayText" href="#" onclick="toggle();">Show Further Details Specification</a>    
<div id="toggleText" style="display:none;"><h1>peek-a-boo</h1></div>​
```

Comment: thankyou, it has worked great. I have used the onclick rather than putting it in href.

Comment: Is there any reason as to why you define the `ele` and `text` variables inside the function, rather than outside it?

Comment: No, but actually if you want to improve performance in IE 6 and 7, you should set to null all variables not used anymore (like ele and text at the end of the function), so they can be garbage collected.